# Angular2 CanActivate guard not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-security

I'm using the `Observable<boolean>` return for `canActivate()`.
The following function was set up for testing, and it resolves correctly, the component displays.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
  return Observable.from([{ admin: true }]).map(x =>
  {
    if (x.admin) return true;
    return false;
  });
}
```

However, the behavior of the actual code is that I stay on the login component despite the console output indicating the route should activate.  The only real difference to the test above is I'm calling a service `this.auth.isAdmin()` instead of using `Observable.from`.  The result of `this.auth.isAdmin()` is an `Observable<boolean>` with a value of true.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
  const isAdmin$ = this.auth.isAdmin();
  return isAdmin$.map(x =>
  {
    console.log('isAdmin returned ' + x);
    if (!x) {
      console.log('redirectToLogin');
      this.auth.redirectToLogin(state.url);
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log('canActivate = true');
      return true;
    }
  });  
}
```

Here is the routing:

```
{
  path: 'admin',
  canActivate: [AdminGuard],
  children: [
    ...adminRoutes
  ]
},
```

Here is my console output:

```
isAdmin returned false
admin-guard.service.ts:27redirectToLogin
auth.service.ts:36 navigating to stored path "/admin"
auth.service.ts:21 Object {isAdmin: true, isPaid: false, $key: "xYFs8kMDpKdYKxDw4AL21FtnSWn1"}
admin-guard.service.ts:25 isAdmin returned true
admin-guard.service.ts:31 canActivate = true
```

And here is the isAdmin() function in case that is of interest:

```
isAdmin(): Observable<boolean> {
    if (!this.auth) return Observable.from([false]);
    const uid = this.auth.uid;
    return this.af.database.object(`user/${uid}`).do(x => console.log(x)).map(x => x.isAdmin);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The observable returned by your `isAdmin` function does not complete. AngularFire2 `FirebaseObjectObservable` instances do not complete; they emit objects as the underlying data changes.

Observables returned by guards have to complete. You can ensure this by using `first` (or `take(1)`) to complete the observable when the first value is emitted:

```ts
canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean> {
  const isAdmin$ = this.auth.isAdmin();
  return isAdmin$.first().map(x =>
  {
    console.log('isAdmin returned ' + x);
    if (!x) {
      console.log('redirectToLogin');
      this.auth.redirectToLogin(state.url);
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log('canActivate = true');
      return true;
    }
  });  
}
```

*At the time of writing, it was necessary for the returned observable to complete. However, Angular now calls* [`first`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.1/packages/router/src/router.ts#L932) *on the returned observable, so there is no longer a requirement for the observable to complete.*